# How to return a number with two decimal places in SQL Server without it automatically rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, decimal

This is an odd one, I have a cost price, and an average cost price. The avg is determined by the avg function and compared to the cost price it looks like the below:

```
Cost Price | Average Cost Price
   8.24            8.23897666
```

Now when  i use the below code it changes it to 8.24 even though i am not specifying any round function

```
select cast(8.23897666 as numeric(18,2))
```

I've tried casting it as a float and still it rounds it to .24 even though i want it to only return 2 decimal places.

Can anyone shed any light on this please as i am unsure as to why this is happening? AS regardless of the number before the decimal place i was to return the full number and 2 decimal places.

Comment: You *did* specify rounding - you asked for a number with only two decimal digits when 8 are available. This *has* to be rounded either up or down. For `8.238` the expected result is `8.24`. If you wanted a different result you should explicitly specify the type of rounding you want

Comment: What output did you expect instead of `8.24`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am just expecting the figure to be returned as 8.23. Likewise if i had a number of 102.679999 then i want to return the static figure of 102.67 not .68. Because if the cost price is 8.24 and the average is 8.23890 then it showing 8.24 as the average is wrong because that's the actual cost price and the average cant be the same as the cost.

Comment: The normal expectation is to get `8.24`. At school, the expected result would be `8.24`. Same for accounting, finance, actually any kind of business application. You're asking for truncation instead of rounding. You need to use [ROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)'s third parameter to specify truncation instead of rounding

Comment: As for why everyone except programming languages expects rounding, it's because this *reduces* the error introduced by rounding. Truncation would result in an error of `0.00897666`. Rounding in `0.00102334`. That's 8 times less. If you have only 100K rows, that adds up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `floor()` and integer division:

```
select floor(8.23897666 * 100) / 100
```

Or better yet, use `round()` with a non-`0` third argument:

```
select round(8.23897666, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Or `ROUND(8.23897666,2,1)` to truncate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes, I was typing while you were commenting... Thanks.